# Connect to a server by R (with cmd.exe)

Tags: r, remote-access, putty

I use Putty to connect to a server via the "Raw" connection. I type in the Host Name, the Port and the Connection type (Raw). After opening, I enter a username and password.

Now I would like to connect to this server from R. I know how to type into cmd.exe with R by using "system". For example:

```
system(command = "ipconfig")
```

But my problem is, I do not know what I have to write into the cmd.exe to connect to the server.

The information I have is the host name (like xy.asdf.net), the port, the username and the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody has the same question in the future:

You have to write

```
telnet adress.net Portnumber
```

into cmd.exe. After that you can log in. But

```
system(command = "telnet adress.net Portnumber")
shell(cmd = "telnet adress.net Portnumber")
```

did not both not work so i used following function:

```
con <- socketConnection("adress.net", port = Portnumber, server=FALSE, open="r+b")
writeLines("Username\r", con)
writeLines("Password\r", con)
```

With that, you are good to go without cmd.exe